# I have a problem with applying my logic into python code

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to pandas and I do not know how to apply the following logic into pandas code. All help I can get would be appreciated!

I have, for example, in my dataframe, the following:

```
id    uid  action program     time         sleepTimes
1628  100   5      200      2020-05-20      2020-05-20
1629  100     1    200      2020-05-21      0
```

---

I wanted the column `sleepTimes` of the id 1629 to have the same value of the column `sleepTimes` of the id 1628 since they have the same uid and program. I wanted to apply this to all rows that verify the same condition.

For a general perspetive, I wanted to add to the column `sleepTimes` of `action = 1`, the values of `sleepTimes` of `action = 5` when `actions = 1` have the same value of `uid` and `program` of `action = 5`. How could I do this, using python?

Observation: My dataframe is created using pandas.

Thank you!

EDIT: This is the code I started with.

```
df['sleepTimes'] = np.where(df['action'] == 5, df['time'], 0)
uid = df.loc[df['action'] == 5, 'uid']

def mapping_time (df):
    if (df['action'] == 1).all():
        #compare and check if uid and program are equal to action 1 and action 5. 
        if df['uid'] == df['sleepTimes'] & df['program']:
            df['sleepTimes'] = df.loc[df['action'] == 5, 'time']
    elif (df['action'] == 3).all():
        if(df['uid'] == uid):
            df['sleepTimes'] = sleepTimes
    else:
#it is action = 5
        df['sleepTimes'] = df['time']
```

Comment: first of all, can you share what you tried till now?.....
do you want to drop a duplicate records on basis of uid column right ??

Comment: @user15551268 What they meant was to post your coding attempt. We won't write it for you, but we'll help you fix your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make use of `astype()` and `replace()` method:

```
df['sleepTimes']=df['sleepTimes'].astype(str).replace('0',np.NaN)
```

Finally make use of `groupby()` method and `ffill()` method:

```
df['sleepTimes']=df.groupby('uid')['sleepTimes'].ffill()
```

Now if you print `df` you will get your desired output

```
#output

    id      uid action  program     time    sleepTimes
0   1628    100     5   200     2020-05-20  2020-05-20
1   1629    100     1   200     2020-05-21  2020-05-20
```

Now If you want to perform some operations on 'sleepTimes' then convert it to `datetime[ns]` by using `pd.to_datetime()` method:

```
df['sleepTimes']=pd.to_datetime(df['sleepTimes'])
```

**Edit:**

```
df['sleepTimes']=df.groupby(['uid','program'])['sleepTimes'].ffill()
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! But, with replace() technique, doesnt only replace NaN values with 0? I reproduced your code, but, it only gives me the indexes.

Comment: It replaces `0` with `NaN` not `NaN` with `0`

Comment: I tried again! It did add the timestamps! But, imagine I want them to split based on the uid and program, how could I add the program on the groupby(), is it possible? It just had a few NaN values, does that mean, it did not find any uid similar? Thank you!

Comment: yes it is possible...wait I am making changes in answer for this

Comment: Thank you so much! It is working! I just have some NaN values, but I am assuming is because it did not find uid and program similar, am I right assuming that?